# Hook Page Alter using Page ID

Tags: hooks

Is it possible to use a Page ID to target a specific page i.e.

```
function module_pageid_page_alter(&page){
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By page ID I guess you mean the page path? There isn't a hook like the one you've suggested but you can do basically the same thing in a standard `hook_page_alter()` like so:

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  if ($_GET['q'] == 'node/1') {
    // Do something for node 1
  }
  else if ($_GET['q'] == 'admin') {
    // Do something for the root admin page
  }
}
```