# Which hook to use in a custom module for tracking access to one particular page?

Tags: hooks, theming, 7

I'm probably not fully awake this morning because it seems so trivial but I cannot figure it out.

I need a hook to track when user access a certain page (path = '`export-csv`'). This page is not a node neither a View and neither a form... It is just a "path". And I need a hook that I could use in my custom module's file, not in templates.

I thought of something like `hook_preprocess_page` or but it doesn't seem to work.

I need a hook called before the page is fully loaded because the page is never truly displayed (it is a page for downloading a file and it just shows the download popup).

If you need precisions about my code or something, just ask. But I don't think that it is necessary.

Thanks in advance of course.

**edit**: I found a part of solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28227/hook-page-alter-using-page-id) but I still have trouble because of the nature of the page. I never truly land on the page and I think the hook is not called before the popup happens.

The callback function of this page looks like this:

```
function grap_contact_export_csv_page() {
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"grape-export.csv\";" );
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  $fp = fopen('export.csv', 'r') or die('Impossible d\'accéder au fichier');
  echo fread($fp, filesize('export.csv'));
  fclose($fp);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: Try with hook_menu_alter. Install your module's callback function, do whatever you need in your callback, and when done do a module_load_include for the above callback and call it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I achieved that:

```
function grap_contact_export_csv_page() {
  grap_log_export(); // Calling another function to record tracking in DB
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"grape-export.csv\";" );
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  $fp = fopen('export.csv', 'r') or die('Impossible d\'accéder au fichier');
  echo fread($fp, filesize('export.csv'));
  fclose($fp);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: Why not to use Google Analytics and track it as an event, for example? Not reliable enough?

Comment: Actually, I had to implement a custom tracking system for my company's internal application. Because it is linked to "government's data", I cannot use a third service like Google. :-)

Comment: Oh, makes sense.